# Ubuntu 18.04 - Following packages have unmet dependencies: php7.2-fpm: ... How to solve this error?

Tags: 18.04, php7

I have php version 7.1 in my Ubuntu 18.04.

```
PHP 7.1.33-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2019 19:28:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I would like to install php 7.2 on it and keep both versions. Following this [post](https://www.vultr.com/docs/configure-php-7-2-on-ubuntu-18-04) I've got the follow outputs:

```
apt-cache pkgnames | grep php7.2
```

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install php -y

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php : Depends: php7.2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have found [similar errors](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9guyd0/ubuntu_1804_lts_trying_to_install_php72_receiving/) and possible solutions in the internet. Most of them was about the content in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I just added the follow (uncommented): `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe

#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main multiverse restricted universe
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main multiverse restricted universe
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main multiverse restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

I still have the same error.
And this is what I have inside the `ect/php`:
[image]

And this is what I see in the apt list

```
ila@ila:~$ apt list php
Listing... Done
php/bionic,bionic 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all
ila@ila:~$ rmadison
E: need at least one package name as an argument.
ila@ila:~$ rmadison php
 php | 1:7.0+35ubuntu6   | xenial         | all
 php | 1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1 | xenial-updates | all
 php | 1:7.2+60ubuntu1   | bionic         | all
 php | 2:7.2+69ubuntu1   | disco          | all
 php | 2:7.3+69ubuntu2   | eoan           | all
 php | 2:7.3+69ubuntu2   | focal          | all
ila@ila:~$ apt list php
Listing... Done
php/bionic,bionic 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all
ila@ila:~$ sudo apt install php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php : Depends: php7.2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After remove the 7.2 and 7.3 directories the error is still there.
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I have found an answer:

Following this [post](http://Upgrade/Install%20to%20PHP%207.2%20-%20Ubuntu%20&%20Debian), I just did:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates`
- `sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg`
- `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'`
- `sudo apt update`
- `dpkg -l | grep php | tee packages.txt` (check the content)
- `sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm` (install the basic)

Then

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.24-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 18:29:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

And I still have my projects working with php7.1 and the new 7.2.

```
ila@ila:/etc/php$ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 21 12:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 161 root root 12288 Nov 21 12:14 ../
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jul 26  2018 7.1/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 21 12:24 7.2/
ila@ila:/etc/php$ tree 7.2/
7.2/
├── cli
│   ├── conf.d
│   │   ├── 10-opcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/opcache.ini
│   │   ├── 20-json.ini -> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/json.ini
│   │   └── 20-readline.ini -> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/readline.ini
│   └── php.ini
├── fpm
│   ├── conf.d
│   │   ├── 10-opcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/opcache.ini
│   │   ├── 20-json.ini -> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/json.ini
│   │   └── 20-readline.ini -> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/readline.ini
│   ├── php-fpm.conf
│   ├── php.ini
│   └── pool.d
│       └── www.conf
└── mods-available
    ├── json.ini
    ├── opcache.ini
    └── readline.ini

6 directories, 13 files
```

Or install some available modules

`sudo apt install -y php7.2-bz2 php7.2-common php7.2-cgi php7.2-cli php7.2-dba php7.2-dev libphp7.2-embed php7.2-bcmath php7.2-fpm php7.2-gmp php7.2-mysql php7.2-tidy php7.2 php7.2-sqlite3 php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-sybase php7.2-curl php7.2-ldap php7.2-phpdbg php7.2-imap php7.2-xml php7.2-xsl php7.2-intl php7.2-zip php7.2-odbc php7.2-mbstring php7.2-readline php7.2-gd php7.2-interbase php7.2-snmp php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-pspell php7.2-pgsql php7.2-enchant php7.2-recode`

Answer (score 0):

If you getting error like `php7.2`  `php7.2-curl` `libapache2-mod-php` doesn't have installable candidate or not locate any package or dependencies is `php7.2-common` Or `libcurl3` Do this . Remeber Change your package name as per your requirements

You have to tackle in mature way. Install aptitude these ubuntu package manager will finds all dependencies, and will install one by one.

```
apt-get install aptitude
```

Now you have to check if aptitude can download it or not if download it follow instructions

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-curl
```

If you have gotten any error like this

```html
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-curl'
```

Any type on error i'm not talking about proper these errors

Try to add php package again

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update
```

Now try this command

```
sudo aptitude install php7.2-curl
```

Aptitude will ask you you want to keep current version of all dependencies

```html
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     php7.2-curl [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Type `n` then `Enter`

Aptitude will find all dependencies and ask you to install all package type

```
y
```

Again

```
y
```

Then

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

For centos of rhel

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

It will Not enabling PHP 7.2 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.2 FPM in Apache2 do

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif

a2enconf php7.2-fpm
```

This method is not only for this error you can find any of php apache2 or ubuntu system package solution using aptitude.

```
Upvote if you find your solution
```